# Getting some errors with axios in a react.js app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Please someone tell me why am I getting this error from this app:

index.js:

```js
const API='http://my-domain.com/api/?format=json'

class App extends React.Component{
 constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state={
   data: [],
   isLoading: false,
   error: null,
  };
 }
 
 componentDidMount(){
  this.setState({isLoading: true});
  axios.get(API)
   .then(response => this.setState({data: response.data, isLoading: false}))
   .catch(response => this.setState({error: response.error, isLoading: false}));
 }
 
 render(){
  return (
   <div>
   <p>{this.state.error}</p>
   <p>{this.state.isLoading ? 'Loading...':'Loaded'}</p>
   <ul>{this.state.data.map(obj => <li key={obj.id}>{obj}</li>)}</ul>
   </div>
  )
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

This is the json that this app should get:

```
[{"id":5,"name":"Storey-1","Value":1399511075,"NSt":5},
{"id":6,"name":"Storey-2","Value":1344981250,"NSt":5},
{"id":7,"name":"Storey-3","Value":1363157800,"NSt":5}]
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id,
>   name, Value, NSt}). If you meant to render a collection of children,
>   use an array instead. in li (at index.js:29) in ul (at index.js:29) in
>   div (at index.js:26) in App (at index.js:36)

Comment: What are you expecting this to output? `<li key={obj.id}>{obj}</li>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id,
>   name, Value, NSt}). If you meant to render a collection of children,
>   use an array instead. in li (at index.js:29) in ul (at index.js:29) in
>   div (at index.js:26) in App (at index.js:36)

This is not an axios error. Is a React error thrown when trying to put a raw object as a React child component.

The error is in this line:

```
 <ul>{this.state.data.map(obj => <li key={obj.id}>{obj}</li>)}</ul>
```

Don't use the whole **obj** object, you must use an object field like this:

```
<ul>{this.state.data.map(obj => <li key={obj.id}>{obj.name}</li>)}</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're mapping through an array of objects in which you're trying to render the object itself:

`<ul>{this.state.data.map(obj => <li key={obj.id}>{obj}</li>)}</ul>`.

I assume you want to render `{obj.name}` or `{obj.Value}`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message is pretty clear. You are attempting to render on object and React doesn't like that:

```
<ul>{this.state.data.map(obj => <li key={obj.id}>{obj}</li>)}</ul>
```

As a next step, you might want to stringify and then pick out the properties you want rendered.  Then, you can see what the response data is and decide how to render.

```
<ul>{this.state.data.map(obj => <li key={obj.id}>{JSON.stringify(obj)}</li>)}</ul>
```

Comment: That's a pretty loose answer, the question for the OP is what they want to render, not `You might want to stringify`

Comment: @DarrenSweeney thanks for the comment, but this is something I often do in order to figure out what I might want to render from the response.  It is a logical next step.  I'm not sure what is in the response data so I can't suggest anything better.  If you have a better suggestion, that would be great.

Comment: My suggestion is this is not an answer - it's a comment really, I get what you mean, hence your answer almost mirrors my comment but to me, an answer with a question or doubt e.g. `you might` is just not a definitive answer imho

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Sorry, I couldn't tell if you were trolling :)  - My answer to the OP about *why* is in my first sentance - because rendering an object is not allowed - as the error message says.  Then rest is just trying to be helpful.

Comment: Ha ha `I couldn't tell if you were trolling :)` I don't even know what that means! I guess I'm behind on social media speak - it's no biggie mate, just wanted to voice what my thoughts are on what constitutes answers on here - 49k is a great rep, this was not a dig

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are receiving an object in

```
<ul>{this.state.data.map(obj => <li key={obj.id}>{obj}</li>)}</ul>
```

with the `{obj}` so if you need the entire object, you can transform it to string with JSON.stringify like so (but I think it would be better to abstract this functionality into a separate function):

```
<li key={obj.id}>{JSON.stringify(obj)}</li>
```